# aws lambda get-account-settings returns 'str' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-sam-cli, aws-config

```
sam --version
SAM CLI, version 1.0.0
aws --version
aws-cli/1.18.79 Python/3.7.6 Darwin/19.6.0 botocore/1.17.7
```

The issue:

```
$ aws lambda get-account-settings
'str' object has no attribute 'get'
```

In `~/.aws/config` shown below in its entirety:

```
[default]
gregion=None
output=json
region=us-east-1
s3=
signature_version=s3v4

[profile my_name]
region=us-east-1
output=json
```

Question: is my SAM CLI not configured properly? How to properly configure Lambda related defaults such as concurrency limits and display account-settings?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your ~/.aws/config file is incorrect. Specifically how you have specified sigv4. It should be like this:

```
[default]
region = us-east-1
s3 =
    signature_version = s3v4
```